# Query/Filter by nested objects getting unexpected results in some nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, filtering

I'm having *weird* results on *some* nested objects that I can't understand.
I mean, in mapping the nested objects are all the same, they have an *id* and a *tree* id also, both are `long` and thats it, but *profession* and *category* do *not* return the expected values, *but* the others do (*professionType*, *professionSubtype* and *attributeType*).

So I got index mapped as:

#### Mapping:

```
{
  "attribute-tree": {
    "mappings": {
      "attribute": {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
          "attributeType": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {"type": "long"},
              "tree": {"type": "long"}
            }
          },
          "category": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {"type": "long"},
              "tree": {"type": "long"}
            }
          },
          "family": {"type": "long"},
          "id": {"type": "long"},
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "parentTree": {"type": "long"},
          "profession": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {"type": "long"},
              "tree": {"type": "long"}
            }
          },
          "professionSubtype": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {"type": "long"},
              "tree": {"type": "long"}
            }
          },
          "professionType": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {"type": "long"},
              "tree": {"type": "long"}
            }
          },
          "sorter": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {"type": "long"},
              "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "tree": {"type": "long"}
            }
          },
          "suggester": {
            "type": "completion",
            "index_analyzer": "edgeNGram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer",
            "payloads": true,
            "preserve_separators": true,
            "preserve_position_increments": true,
            "max_input_length": 50
          },
          "tree": {"type": "long"},
          "type": {"type": "string"}
        }
      },
      "division": {
        // same as "attribute"
      },
      "profession-subtype": {
        // same as "attribute"
      },
      "profession-type": {
        // same as "attribute"
      },
      "profession": {
        // same as "attribute"
      },
      "category": {
        // same as "attribute"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If any kind of information is missing, please say

Thanks in advance

### Example

#### Filtering by *category.id*:

```
POST /attribute-tree/_search
{
  "size": 2,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
       "term": {"category.id": 1}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 31,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "attribute-tree",
            "_type": "category",
            "_id": "4064",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 1,
               "tree": 4064,
               "name": "Profession",
               "type": "C",
               "parentTree": 4063,
               "profession": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "professionType": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 1
               },
               "professionSubtype": {
                  "id": 6,
                  "tree": 4063
               },
               "category": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "attributeType": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "family": [
                  4063,
                  1
               ],
               "suggester": {
                  "input": [
                     "Profession"
                  ],
                  "output": "Profession"
               },
               "sorter": {
                  "name": "Profession",
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 4064
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "attribute-tree",
            "_type": "category",
            "_id": "4083",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 1,
               "tree": 4083,
               "name": "Profession",
               "type": "C",
               "parentTree": 4082,
               "profession": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "professionType": {
                  "id": 2,
                  "tree": 4072
               },
               "professionSubtype": {
                  "id": 8,
                  "tree": 4082
               },
               "category": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "attributeType": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "family": [
                  4082,
                  4072
               ],
               "suggester": {
                  "input": [
                     "Profession"
                  ],
                  "output": "Profession"
               },
               "sorter": {
                  "name": "Profession",
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 4083
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

> Notice that on this example the category.id doesn't have the expected value (this is also valid for when it is *0* instead of *null*)

However I have nodes with category.id = 1:

```
POST /attribute-tree/_search
{
  "size": 2,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
       "term": {"tree": 4}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Item:

```
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "attribute-tree",
            "_type": "profession",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 1,
               "tree": 4,
               "name": "A&R Administrator",
               "type": "P",
               "parentTree": 3,
               "profession": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "professionType": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 1
               },
               "professionSubtype": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 2
               },
               "category": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 3
               },
               "attributeType": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "family": [
                  3,
                  2,
                  1
               ],
               "suggester": {
                  "input": [
                     "A&R",
                     "Administrator"
                  ],
                  "output": "A&R Administrator"
               },
               "sorter": {
                  "name": "A&R Administrator",
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 4
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

#### Filtering by *professionType.id*:

```
POST /attribute-tree/_search
{
  "size": 2,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
       "term": {"professionSubtype.id": 1}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get:

```
{
   "took": 7,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3890,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "attribute-tree",
            "_type": "category",
            "_id": "251",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 4,
               "tree": 251,
               "name": "Medium",
               "type": "C",
               "parentTree": 2,
               "profession": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "professionType": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 1
               },
               "professionSubtype": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 2
               },
               "category": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "attributeType": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "family": [
                  2,
                  1
               ],
               "suggester": {
                  "input": [
                     "Medium"
                  ],
                  "output": "Medium"
               },
               "sorter": {
                  "name": "Medium",
                  "id": 4,
                  "tree": 251
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "attribute-tree",
            "_type": "profession",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": 1,
               "tree": 4,
               "name": "A&R Administrator",
               "type": "P",
               "parentTree": 3,
               "profession": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "professionType": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 1
               },
               "professionSubtype": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 2
               },
               "category": {
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 3
               },
               "attributeType": {
                  "id": null,
                  "tree": null
               },
               "family": [
                  3,
                  2,
                  1
               ],
               "suggester": {
                  "input": [
                     "A&R",
                     "Administrator"
                  ],
                  "output": "A&R Administrator"
               },
               "sorter": {
                  "name": "A&R Administrator",
                  "id": 1,
                  "tree": 4
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

#### Also tested as:

```
POST /attribute-tree/_search
{
  "query":{
    "filtered": {
      "query": {"match_all":{}},
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "category",
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {"term": {"category.id": 1}}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this gives an error

```
org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [attribute-tree] [nested] nested object under path [category] is not of nested type
```

Comment: as per the mapping category is  [object type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-object-type.html) and not [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html). If you need to use the nested filter it should be of type nested .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mapping it looks like the index has a type of `category` as well as a field in `attribute` type called `category`.

To allow for proper field resolution and disambiguate between field `id` in type `category` vs field `category.id` in type `attribute` you would need to specify the entire path to the field including the type i.e `<type>.<fieldname>`.

Example:

```
POST /attribute-tree/_search
{
  "size": 2,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
       "term": {"attribute.category.id": 1}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This [issue thread](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4081) has more discussion with regard to this.

Comment: Actually that worked, but still got the problem, because i intend to search on all core's. I've tried with `*.category.id` but it didn't work, do you have a suggestion ? thanks

Comment: a tedious workaround `should` clause with multiple  terms filter for `category.id` on each type ,

Comment: another option is to restructure the index since all types have same "schema" create a single type .The document should contain  `document-type` field along with current data.

Comment: When you mean single type, you're talking in merging the attributes, categories, professions, etc... into one, is that correct?

Comment: Actually I was thinking in what arm can that do, but I can split them by the values in the objects, so I'm going to give it a try.